# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL ARC Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I want to render PDFs on iOS and I'm getting a memory leak when I call **CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL()**. I know this issue has been discussed before, but I don't know whether my conditions are different because I'm using ARC.

I've extracted and simplified the problem by running the following code on my viewDidLoad:

```
// Bridge resourceRef to ARC with no ownership change (still owned by ARC)
CFURLRef resourceRef = (__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath];

CGPDFDocumentRef pdf;
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(resourceRef);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);

// Do not need to release resourceRef because ARC will release it
```

Instruments tells me that the Leaked Object is a Malloc 48 Bytes, responsible by CoreGraphics. And the stacktrace has CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL in it. Leaking means that there is object out there without an owner.

I've create a git repo with a replication of the problem:
https://github.com/indika/PDFLeaks

Any ideas. Would appreciate any help or 'pointers'.

Comment: I might have found the reason behind the leak: if my PDF originates from the NSCachesDirectory directory, then the leak occurs. Perhaps I should use a different directory for downloadable content.

Comment: I might be wrong about the leak being dependant on the directory the pdf is located

Comment: I ran the project from your link but it shows no leaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made many mistakes, especially with double releasing the document reference. However, that wasn't the real critter in my situation.

I was loading a broken PDF! I was using pdftk to slice and merge pdf documents, and I was breaking the indexes. So remember, after merging a PDF with pdftk, repair the file with:

```
pdftk original output destination
```

Answer (score 1):

resourceRef is going to be overreleased.  Take a look at what you are doing.

1) Bridge `resourceRef` to ARC with no ownership change (still owned by ARC)

2) `CFRelease` on `resourceRef`

3) ARC also releases `resourceRef`

You don't need step 2

This is not a memory leak though, but an overrelease.